# Is this geometry problem possible? If so, how do you solve it. More info in the images

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

More infomation is in the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC1Ih.jpg

In case you can't read my handwriting:

GIVENS:

lengths of

BC, CD, DE, EF, GB, GC, GD, GE, GF, DA

angles of

GBC, GCD, GDE, GEF, GFE, BGC, CGD, DGE, EGF, BAC, CAD, DAE, EAF

WE NEED:

Any of the following angles:

ABC, ACD, ADE, AEF, AFE

Comment: Your diagram shows several equalities that are not explicitly written.  Are the indicated equalities also in use?

Answer (score 1):

The only constraint that limits $A$ is the given length of $\overline{DA}$, consequently, $A$ can be anywhere on the circle having that given length as radius, centered on $D$.

Comment: Sorry but I posted the wrong information. I just updated. There is a little bit more information about A, not sure if that changes anything.